# How to detect Web Cam is attached or not Using java

Tags: java

How to detect whether the Web cam is attached to computer or not by using Java?

Comment: Do you mean using a browser or locally?

Comment: Just completed my answer with the installation steps on Linux

Answer (score 2):

[JMF](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/index.jsp) ([Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/samples/)) should be able to detect any media, including a webcam.

Potentially through `CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList();`

---

For "installing JMF on Linux", one way is simply to:

- [download it](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html).
- Change directories to the install location.
- Run the command

:

```
  % /bin/sh ./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin
```

Comment: Need to know how to install JMF on Linux .Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code I use in a simple Webcam client with JMF:

```
Format format = new RGBFormat();
MediaLocator cameraLocator = null;
// get device list
Vector deviceList = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(format);
// if devices available
if(deviceList != null && deviceList.size() > 0) {
  // pick first
  CaptureDeviceInfo device = (CaptureDeviceInfo) deviceList.get(0);
  cameraLocator = device.getLocator();
}
```

It picks the first available webcam. Of course, after having the webcam you can store the cameraLocator and try to re-open it on the 2nd run.